# Rspec newbie question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I was looking at some rspec sample code and came across this -

```
lambda { 
  @my_object.function
}.should raise_error(ArgumentError, "Unknown tag type")
```

Does this mean that rspec monkey patches the `Proc` object? Or otherwise how can I call the `should` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably wouldn't call it monkey patching since it extends the core ruby Object class. But: yes, rspec will define the should method on Object so anything can be say that it should "something"

```
1.should eq(2)

class MySuperObject
end

MySuperObject.new.should_not respond_to(:monkey!)
```

Comment: There's an excellent screencast here: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/building-rspec-from-scratch on building a rspec like library from scratch (15 minutes)

Comment: It actually extends `Kernel` module. But since that's mixed-in, everything gets it. I'm not sure this matters other than clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely it specifically monkey patches `Proc` since everything responds to `should`. Does this behavior really matter? Regardless, an easy choice is to just take a peek at the source. https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec, specifically https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/expectations/extensions/kernel.rb

More about `Kernel` http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html